union of "elementary domains" (Elementargebiete) necessarily has to be "elementary domain"?
I got the following exercise (translated from German):
A domain $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is called "elementary domain" (orig.: Elementargebiet) iff every holomorphic function $\_ : G \to \mathbb{C}$ posesses an antiderivative. Prove: If $G$ and $G'$ are elementary domains and $G \cap G'$ is connected, then $G \cup G'$ is also a "elementary domain".
If the intersection isn't empty I have no problem to solve it. Furthermore, it should be quite easier to in theory if the intersection is indeed empty (I assume the empty set is connected) because you could skip the only "annoyance" of the intersection. Now comes my problem.
There seems to exist no direct translation for the term Elementargebiet but in theory it should be simply connected domain, right? But if so and the intersection is empty, then the union isn't connected. But in the german wikipidia they say that all "elementary domains" are simply connected(1).
So what is right and what is wrong?

"Elementary domain" is a highly nonstandard terminology. From the topological viewpoint, this means a domain with vanishing 1-st homology group.

To confuse matters, at least in English, the empty set isn't always considered connected.

That's interesting and could explain the issue. On the other hand that's rather surprising. I thought it would be connected, since it cannot by divided into two disjoint open non-empty sets.

I guess an Elementargebiet then is an open set, such that each of its connected components is simply connected. But if "Gebiete" have to be connected, as is usual, then that case has to be excluded, which we could do by saying the empty set is not connected. In any case, the remaining issue seems to be more one about terminology and conventions than understanding, so no need to worry a lot.
